# Parse Set Object To UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, parse-platform

So this is my first time working with parse I have simple application which creates a user and allows them to sign in. I'm currently working on something that will allow them to fill in details about themselves using PFObjects, I don't have a problem with that. My issue is I need to get user specific data print out on an UILabel.

Here's my code creating a PFObject this works fine:

```
- (IBAction)saveProfile:(id)sender {
    PFObject *profile = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Profile"];
    [profile setObject: self.name.text forKey:@"name"];
    [profile setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"author"];
    [profile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"No Error");
        }else NSLog(@"Yeah you got an error bro");
    }];


}
```

Here's what I'm having an issue with my PFQuery:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Profile"];
    [query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
            self.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", query];
        }
        else {
        NSLog(@"Fail");
        }
    }];
}
```

So basicly I want the user to enter their name have it save, and have that specific user's name print out on a label. This is as far as I got so, if you have any suggestions I'm all ears. Thanks!

Updated:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Profile"];
    [query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
            self.nameLabel.text = object[@"name"];
        }
        else {
        NSLog(@"Fails");
        }
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're setting the `PFObject` "name" key to self.name.text, but in your `PFQuery` you're querying the class and asking for values where "name" is equal to `[PFUser currentUser]`.  You're setting the value one way then using a completely different value in an attempt to query the object; so `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock` isn't returning an object since there's no Profile object where "name" equals `[PFUser currentUser]`.

I think you're confusing your "name" and "author" properties...

---

Edit (in response to your comment):

OK, so in `saveProfile:` you're creating a `PFObject` where you're setting "name" to the name string and "author" to the user's PFUser object. When you're using `whereKey:` to perform a query on this class in an effort to retrieve the object using `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:`, the result returned to you will be the *full* first `PFObject` where the object associated with the key is the one specified in the `whereKey:` criteria.  So you don't have to specify which key of the PFObject you want to read before performing `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:`. The query returns the *whole* object -- name, author, etc.

So in order to access the returned `PFObject`'s "name" within the query block, change:

```
self.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", query];
```

to (`dispatch_aync` added to force the label change onto the main thread):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    self.nameLabel.text = object[@"name"];
});
```

Comment: I'm kinda confused about the whole thing now, haha. I successfully create "name" and author is a pointer to the user that created "name". So I want the "name" of that specific user to print out.

Comment: OK, I see. I'll explain how to do this. One sec.

Comment: I changed `self.nameLabel.text = object[@"name"];` but the name is still not showing on my label.

Comment: I'm confused on this line here `[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[name];`

Comment: Yeah you need to also change the query like I said to [query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:name]; where name = self.name.text

Comment: It doesnt allow me to change it to name

Comment: You have to create a NSString *name variable and store the self.name.text string within name. Or better yet, query based on the author value instead and change your query whereTo: to [query whereKey:@"author" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; That way the object value will always be accessible and associated with the correct user.

Comment: Ok I changed that, but it's still not working. I updated the question with my code.

Comment: Hm... That looks really good to me now. Except for the fact that you may need to update the label on the main thread, ex.  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{ self.nameLabel.text = object[@"name"]; });  And are you 100% sure your PFObject's originally posting to your database? Can you see the object in your Parse console?

Comment: Positive it's there, I can see it just not presenting on the label.

Comment: OK, then try adding the dispatch_async as I did in the above edit. If that doesn't work, double check to make sure that your label outlet is connected because otherwise, everything in your code looks really good now...

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

only works if the "name" column is a pointer or relation to the User class. If it is the username you're after, you need to use

```
[query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser][@"username"]];
```

But why are you querying for the object you just saved?

Your last, updated example should work for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You could fire up a query like the one below

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Profile"];

NSString *nameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[PFUser currentUser]objectForKey:@"name"]];

[query whereKey:@"name" containsString:nameStr];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
{

  if (!error)
  {             
    /*object contains all columns and you need only key to obtain value*/

   nameLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object[@"job"];
   .
   .
   .
 }
 else
 {
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }
}];
```

Now you will have object of current user along with its all details. Also you could do a thing, i.e., At time of user filling up profile details save it in a dictionary as below :

```
NSDictionary *signupDetail = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.userRegisterTextField.text, @"username",
                               self.nameTextField.text, @"Name",
                               [ResponseDict objectForKey:@"sessionToken"] ,@"sessionToken",
                               [ResponseDict objectForKey:@"objectId"], @"objectId", 
                               nil];         
//ResponseDict is dictionary you get in response for successful signup.
```

Then you could store it using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` so you will have all info of user at one place and call it wherever needed.